# Trying to request access token from Google oauth2

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0

i'am trying to get started with dealing googles oauth2

My application vill be so called server application. it should be workin wihtout user input. My code so far(only trying to get access token):

```
   Dim strToken = Request.QueryString("code")

        Dim strExchange = "response_type=code"
        strExchange += "&redirect_uri=http://xxxx.zzzzz.com/test/google.aspx"
        strExchange += "&client_id=xxxx7hju.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        strExchange += "&scope=&"
        strExchange += "client_secret=yJpGI1yQBCvvxxxxx&grant_type=authorization_code"
        Dim url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"
        Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(url & strExchange)

        Response.Write(result)
```

This gives me bad reguest (400)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869770/Handling-events-in-google-calendar-using-google) which handles the google calender entries. their you are able to get proper documentation for oauth2.0 authentication technique. Hope that all the values ware taken from App.Config

```
 clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("client_id").ToString
 clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("client_secret").ToString
 redirecturi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("redirect").ToString
 mainUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("mainuser").ToString
Public Sub authorize()
        Dim Uri As String = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=" & clientId & "&redirect_uri=" & redirecturi & "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&login_hint=" & mainUser & "&include_granted_scopes=true"
        Response.Redirect(Uri)
End Sub
```

Comment: Main user the mail id of authenticating user

Comment: The redirect URI in the request: http://xx.xxxx.xom/xx/google.aspx did not match a registered redirect URI. I got this. Is there some place on api console I should add the url on?

Comment: Ya definitely  you have to set the redirect URI in developer console. Have you red the article which i had referenced?

Comment: Ok. now i got it.  but Do I alway have to allow acces to analytics by mouse  click?  Thsi app have to totally invisible to end user. As I am going to use this on server to server usage. My server -> google server. At the end user gets the data from analytics trough our database .

Comment: I would just need simple example of oAuth2 login with googles service account. What do I have to do step by step? I have been googling a lot around this problem.